# How to convert HttpServletRequest to Java Object in HandlerInterceptorAdapter

Tags: java, spring, rest, servlets

When I build RESTFull service using Spring, I need to do special handle for every request. So I introduce interceptor. The problem is my parameter is Java object defined by myself. How can I convert HttpServletRequest to my object? The request Type maybe JSON, maybe XML.

```
public class RequestInterceptors extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {
  @Override
  public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {

    CslRequestmyReq = new CslRequest();
    // Convert request to myReq ????
    return true;
  }
}
```

I tried below method, not working...

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES,   false);
CslRequest re = mapper.readValue(request.getInputStream(), CslRequest.class);
```

OR

```
HttpEntity entity = new InputStreamEntity(request.getInputStream(),
            request.getContentLength());
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(entity.getContent());
CslRequest o = (CslRequest) ois.readObject();
```

Comment: You will run into issues when you try to parse the request twice. What do you need to do specifically. Why did you introduce your own object, what is the purpose of this.

Comment: Michael, i will not parse the request twice. What i want to do is convert to my own object and force set value for one of the attribute. Say, cslRequest.setName("Derek") for every reqeust.

Comment: What attribute? Also please read my name I'm not michael. And yes you will be reading it twice once in your controller and next in the handler (aka controller)... But again be more descriptive of your usecase instead of being vague about it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this : 
// @RequestBody allow to get the header into a string object or something else

public boolean preHandle(@RequestBody String handler) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        CslRequest re;
        try {
            re = mapper.readValue(handler, CslRequest.class);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
             Error parsing object
        }return true;
    }
```

Comment: i am implementing HandlerInterceptor, and can not over write preHandle like this: public boolean preHandle(@RequestBody String handler) throws IOException {}